# Advance jmeter books or tutorials?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new in Advance jmeter, I already purchase the Jmeter book for beginner & read the basics of jmeter(good book for basics). Now my problem, Please suggest book or tutorial for advance Jmeter concepts (Advance jmeter concepts in single place)? I have already going through the User manual but it is difficult to understand & language is too difficult.

Comment: There has been a similar question on StackExchange's Software Quality Assurance & Testing:
http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/where-can-i-find-good-jmeter-tutorials

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it is useful but Is there any specific book to check all the advance concepts in single place?